# Google Maps InfoWindow - Prevent html template from showing on page

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-maps

I'm working on a personal project which will have Google Maps on a couple of pages. I'm creating just a sample demo page and I'm stuck on something that seems very simple but I couldn't get around it (Not much of a front-end developer)

I have a Html page with my map. At the bottom, I created a "template" which will be used as the container for the infoWindow content.

```
<div class="infowindow2">
    <h3>Point Information</h3>
    <h4>Id {id} </h4>
    <h4>Update date: {update}</h4>
</div>
```

I have the following css style for the infowindow2 class:

```
.infowindow2{
   width:250px;
   height:130px;
   overflow:hidden;
}
```

On the click event of the marker, I set the infoWindow content:

```
    function addMarkerClick(marker){

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {

            infoWindow.close();         

            //Retrieve html template
            var window2 = $('.infowindow2')[0].outerHTML;

            //Replace template holders with values
            window2 = window2.replace("{id}", marker.id);
            window2 = window2.replace("{update}", marker.update);

            infoWindow.setContent(window2);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);        
        });     
    }
```

Now down to my question. Everything is working fine except for one thing. The Html template for the window is showing up on the page. I tried to hide the window by setting the display to none via css but when I click, the infoWindow is empty (As expected, the html is not on the page)

Am I missing something here? I would like to have the html template defined on my page but only use it for the infoWindow . I would like not to use any css framework like bootstrap right now, because this is a very basic demo.

UPDATE: JSFiddle reproducing the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/joaopgrassi/vtp4fq97/1/
Scroll down the page to see the html template being displayed.

Comment: can you recreate this in a fiddle?

Comment: Sure. Updated the question with jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the content and html right in the variable, no need to pull it from the page:

```
var window2 = '<h3>Point Information</h3>'+
    '<h4>Id: '+ marker.id +'</h4>'+
    '<h4>Update Date:'+ marker.update +'</h4>';
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vtp4fq97/3/)

UPDATE

I would not consider that bad practice. Either you hard code it in your variable or you hard code it at the bottom of the page. If you do it at the bottom of the page not only are you adding code that essentially is doing nothing except there to be copied, but you have to swap out all of the variables. It adds several extra steps of unnecessary code. But it's up to you. If you want it the way you had it just set `display: none` on `.infowindow2` and call:

```
var window2 = $('.infowindow2').html();
```

instead of `outerHTML`

[NEW FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vtp4fq97/4/)

it's doing the same thing, but the text you have just fits the box. To keep the styles you want on `.info-box` I would wrap that in a `div` and add `display: none` to that. Then grab the html inside of that one. New Fiddle:

[THIRD TIME IS A CHARM](http://jsfiddle.net/vtp4fq97/5/)

Comment: Yes, I know that. But it seems to me a bad practice to hard code the html template like this. Also this is a very small example only for question purposes. In the real scenario it will be way more complex layout.

Comment: Thanks! I get what you are saying. For sure, hardcoding on the page or in a variable is the same thing. My point is, I think is a bit more 'clean' to have the html pre-defined even though it is just sitting there than having to concatenate a string and all that. One question only. I used the .html() before and it returned only the inside elements (as designed). How this works now? It is because of the display:none?